# Method info(<MultiArgumentClosure===true>) from Mockery_0_Illuminate_Log_LogManager should be called exactly 1 times but called 0 times

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

Hello I am writing a test on laravel 9.

Here's my simple code

```
public function it_can_keep_sale_order()
{
    DB::beginTransaction();

    $all['data'][] = [
        "id"        => 1, # product ID
        "name"      => "Latuda",
        "quantity"  => "5",
        "branch_id" => "1",
    ];

    $response = $this->postJson('api/sales/order/keep', $all, ['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->token]);
    $response->assertStatus(200);

    $data = $response->getData();

    $response->assertJson([
        "data" => [
            'status'    => true,
            'message'   => "Successful",
            'reference' => $data->data->reference,
            'data'      => $all
        ]
    ]);

    Log::shouldReceive('info')
        ->once()
        ->withArgs(function ($message) {
            return strpos($message, 'Creating sales order') !== false;
        });

    DB::rollBack();
}
```

The issue encountered in this line

```
Log::shouldReceive('info')
        ->once()
        ->withArgs(function ($message) {
            return strpos($message, 'Creating sales order') !== false;
        });
```

With a response

```
Method info(<MultiArgumentClosure===true>) from Mockery_0_Illuminate_Log_LogManager should be called
 exactly 1 times but called 0 times.


at vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:98
     94▕ unset($options);
     95▕ 
     96▕ require PHPUNIT_COMPOSER_INSTALL;
     97▕ 
  ➜  98▕ PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main();
     99▕
```

What is the workaround of this?

Laravel log shows

```
[2023-01-15 23:33:34] testing.INFO: [App\Http\Controllers\SalesOrderController] Creating sales order  
[2023-01-15 23:33:34] testing.INFO: [App\Http\Controllers\SalesOrderController] Created sales order
```

Answer (score 0):

try with `expects()`

```
Log::expects('info')
    ->once()
    ->withArgs(function ($message) {
        return strpos($message, 'Creating sales order') !== false;
    });
```

Reminder `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();`